# How do you rotate the text in textblock in C# (Code-Behind)~~

Tags: wpf, animation, textblock, pixelsense

Basically I am currently doing final year project in my college whereby i am touching on surface 2.0 WPF.

My project is a game whereby if a user answer a question wrongly,the next question will be rotated to make it more difficult. But I am unsure how to do it. I saw an example in msdn microsoft but it only shows XAML codes. I need the C# codes.

**Here's the XAML example.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754028.aspx

The last example

**Here's part of my validation codes. I need to activate the animation if user answer wrongly.**

```
 if (surfaceRadioButton1.IsChecked == true)

{

user_answer = (string)surfaceRadioButton1.Content;

            textBlock2.Text = validateAnswer(user_answer, answer);
            retreiveYellowQns();
            if (textBlock2.Text.Equals("Correct"))
            {
                yellow_coord = yellow_coord + 50;
                Canvas.SetLeft(car, yellow_coord);
                Canvas.SetTop(car, 289);
            }
            else
            {
                if (yellow_coord <= 330)
                {
                    yellow_coord = 330;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(car, yellow_coord);
                    Canvas.SetTop(car, 289);
                }
                else
                {
                    yellow_coord = yellow_coord - 50;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(car, yellow_coord);
                    Canvas.SetTop(car, 289);
                }
            }
        }
```

Any Help will be glad,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one. You can use an animation on the RenderTransform:

```
var rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 180, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var rt = (RotateTransform) textblock2.RenderTransform;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

In your Xaml, you can add the RotateTransform:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
  </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: So should i put that code inside the                                else
                {
                    yellow_coord = yellow_coord - 50;
                    Canvas.SetLeft(car, yellow_coord);
                    Canvas.SetTop(car, 289);

Comment: Yes, put this code to the lines where your text should be rotated (Error validation -> error case) .This will animate your text to be rotated with 180 degrees within 5 Seconds. This will give the user a better visual feedback that it is rotated.

Comment: Thanks,it works. Just one last question. How do i forcefully terminate the animation once the user answer the next question correctly?

Comment: You'll have to wrap your Animations within a BeginStoryboard. Once you've given this Storyboard a name, you can call StopStoryboard with the given name in your "CorrectAnswer" - Handler. Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863722/combining-wpf-datatriggers-and-storyboard-in-code

Answer (score 7):

You will have to use Transformation for this. Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815374/293712

Or You can also try, (I have not tried this) Look at [this article](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2006102701.aspx) for more details

```
textBlock2.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(IntegerAngleValue);
```

Comment: Works like a charm in Winforms! Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
            var rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(180, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            UiImage.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5,0.5);
            UiImage.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform();
            var rt = (RotateTransform)UiImage.RenderTransform;
            rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```